# Why do we usually measure liquids and gases by volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements, error-analysis, volume

Why do measure liquids and gases in volume rather than by weight? Isn't that comparatively more inaccurate since volume changes with temperature and pressure?

Comment: It also matters to be _easy._ Accurate mass balances needed for the kind of accuracy you can get with volume measurements are hard to come by, expensive, and maybe so expensive that they cannot be justified as a purchase. Also, there is no inaccuracy there---changes with temperature and pressure are facts of life that can be fixed, say by defining them, or by using known tables / functions to compensate.

Comment: I think you mean mass and not weight. Weight depends on local gravity and isn't intrinsic to the substance at hand. Volume is easier to work with in many ways. Gasses expand to fill their container, liquids do something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquids are measured by weight as well as volume. Volume is often easier, once you have a calibrated measuring cup. Pour it in until it comes up to the line. And volume of liquid and measuring cup change very little with temperature and pressure.

With electronic scales, measuring by weight is also easy. Put an empty container on the scale and press the Tare button. Fill it until the weight it right. But such scales weren't available in the 1800's when measurements were being standardized. It is less convenient with a mechanical scale.

That works for the kitchen. Chemists and others sometimes need more precise measurements. Both kinds of measurement are still done, and both get more complex. A laboratory scale might weigh to the nearest milligram or better. Weigh a piece of paper, write a word on it, and weigh it again. You can measure the weight of the ink. Some precise flasks have a carefully fitted stopper with a small hole through it. You fill the flask to the top of the hole to get a known volume.

Gasses are much harder to measure by weight. A container full of air weighs just about the same as a container full of gas. Even pressurized tanks weigh about the same full or empty. (Propane tanks are full of liquid that vaporizes at room pressure and temperature.) So you more or less have to use

$$n = \frac{PV}{RT}$$

Given a standard room temperature and a fixed volume tank, a pressure gauge tells you how much gas you have. The tank is "full" when you fill it to the right pressure.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To an extent, it's convenient. You can transport things in an apparatus designed to measure volume, the same is not true of an apparatus designed to measure mass. If I am selling gallon jugs of water, I can design the jug and simply fill it to have a constant quantity of water. If I measured the water by mass instead, I'd have to weigh every single jug to check how much water it held. A volume-measuring device has broader applications as a vessel, compared to the limited uses of a weight-measuring device.

Comment: Manufacturers fill, for example, breakfast cereal boxes by weight. Why is it not possible to do the same when filling jugs of liquid? I'm not saying it would actually be better to do so, but your answer seems to be saying it would somehow be dramatically more difficult to fill liquid containers by weight.

Comment: @ThePhoton I imagine that packers of dry good use weight only because they can't reliably use volume - dry goods can settle or be compressed, so volumetric packing can result in different amounts of material. Most common liquids are entirely incompressible - unlike dry goods, a fixed volume of liquid represents a fixed amount of product matter.